# Ubuntu 21.10 "Running in chroot, ignoring" Problem

Tags: 21.10

I rooted my Redmi Note 10S (Secret) with Magisk v24.1 and installed Ubuntu 21.10.  Most programs say "Running in chroot, ignoring" and don't work.  What should I do?

Example (systemctl): `Running in chroot, ignoring command 'list-units'`